# How do I show different opening hours depending on what day it is?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I'm getting an input from the user on the format yy-mm-dd and from that my program is supposed to decide if it's mon-fri or weekend. I have this bit of code that I thought would work:

```
def opening_hours(self, user_input):
    '''
    Compare month and date of visit with the opening hours for the zoo
    :param user_input: input from user on the format yy-mm-dd
    :return: user_input, day, opening_time_weekday, closing_time_weekday, opening_time_weekend, closing_time_weekend
    '''

    global day, opening_time_weekday, closing_time_weekday, opening_time_weekend, closing_time_weekend

    opening_time_weekday = 14
    closing_time_weekday = 20
    opening_time_weekend = 10
    closing_time_weekend = 22

    user_input = list(map(int, user_input.split('-')))
    day = datetime.date(user_input[0], user_input[1], user_input[2])
    print(day.weekday())

    if day.weekday == 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4:
        print("The zoo is open from " + str(opening_time_weekday) + "-" + str(closing_time_weekday))
    else:
        print("The zoo is open from " + str(opening_time_weekend) + "-" + str(closing_time_weekend))


    return user_input, day, opening_time_weekday, closing_time_weekday, opening_time_weekend, closing_time_weekend
```

When I print day.weekday it prints the right number, so for example if I choose a date that is a saturday it will print 5 since it's the 5th day (starting with 0), but the code will still always print "The zoo is open from 14-20". Can someone please explain why?

Comment: Hi, this `day.weekday == 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4` is incorrect. Should be `day.weekday in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: Your pasring date method is very simple and may be error prone. Consider using  `strptime` from `datetime.datetime`

Comment: Would I write "datetime.datetime.strptime"? I tried but how can I do it so that the user_input[2] still works with it? Right now it says that it's an unexpected argument.

Comment: You can use this `day = datetime.datetime.strptime(user_input, "%y-%m-%d")` to turn "yy-mm-dd" strings into datetime objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `if` statement. In Python `if 1` is the same as `if True`. Therefore, when you do `if day.weekday == 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4:`, you are saying if the weekday is 0 or True or True or True and so on, which will always be true (that's how or works). The correct way to do this is either `if day.weekday == 0 or day.weekday == 1 or day.weekday == 2` and so on, which is quite long and repetitive, or the easier to read, simpler `if day.weekday in [0,1,2,3,4]` or `if day.weekday in range(5)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried both 'if day.weekday in [0,1,2,3,4]' and 'if day.weekday in range(5):' , but the code will always print that the zoo is open from 10-22 (weekend) no matter what day I type in. But thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Change `day.weekday` in the if statement to `day.weekday()` (like you did in the print statement). I should have noticed that when answering, sorry.

Comment: Oh I didn't even think of that. It works fine now, thank you so much!!

Comment: No problem, if you found this answer helpful, please accept it with the green check mark

Answer (score 0):

Interesting bug.

```
    if day.weekday == 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4:
```

That won't work because of the `or` operator. When you use `A or B or C` that means to test if any of `A`, `B`, or `C` is `True`. So in your code, it will always be true because `1` is True, so Python won't even evaluate the rest of the `or` cases.

Try this instead:

```
    if day.weekday in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4):
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've already tried this, but the code will always print that the zoo is open from 10-22 (weekend) no matter what day I type in.

Answer (score 0):

```
def test(foo):
   if foo == 0 or 1:
       print("The value is either 0 or 1")

test(2)
# The value is either 0 or 1
```

You're using the `or` operator incorrectly.

The expression in the if statement always evaluates to True because 1 is a truthy value in Python. Something like `if day.weekday() in range(5):` will work better.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried now to write 'if day.weekday in range(5):' , but the code will always print that the zoo is open from 10-22 (weekend) no matter what day I type in. But thanks for the clarification!

Comment: updating to `day.weekday()` should do the trick !

Comment: Thanks again! I hade forgotten the parentheses :)